# Bug: Wrong limit in Mathematica 11.1.1 and current WolframAlpha

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, bugs, symbolic, special-functions

**Bug introduced around 11.1.1 and fixed in 11.2**

---

```
f[x_] := ( (x+1/2) Log[x] - x + Log[2 Pi]/2 - Log[x!] + 1/(12x) ) x^3
Limit[ f[x], x->Infinity ]
Limit[ f[x] - 1/10368, x->Infinity ]
```

gives (with Mathematica 11.1.1)

```
1/10368
139/51840
```

and the two limits are inconsistent. The second is OK, but the first really is $\displaystyle\frac1{360}$, per Richard P. Brent's [Asymptotic approximation of central binomial coefficients with rigorous error bounds](https://maths-people.anu.edu.au/~brent/pd/rpb267.pdf#page=11) ([arXiv:1608.04834](https://arxiv.org/abs/1608.04834), 2016), OEIS's [A046968](https://oeis.org/A046968)/[A046969](https://oeis.org/A046969), and the [Wikipedia article on Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Stirling%27s_approximation&oldid=841060545#Speed_of_convergence_and_error_estimates).

There's the very same bug with WolframAlpha as of 2018-06-09:
[limit as x goes to infinity of ( (x+1/2) Log[x] - x + Log[2 Pi]/2 - Log[x!] + 1/(12x) ) x^3](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit%20as%20x%20goes%20to%20infinity%20of%20(%20(x%2B1%2F2)%20Log%5Bx%5D%20-%20x%20%2B%20Log%5B2%20Pi%5D%2F2%20-%20Log%5Bx!%5D%20%2B%201%2F(12x)%20)%20x%5E3)
yields $\displaystyle\frac1{10368}\approx0.0000964506$ rather than $\displaystyle\frac1{360}\approx0.00277778$ as is should.

**What's going on? Is there some way to find the internal cause?**

---

Update: the problem vanishes if we change `x!` to `Gamma[x+1]`, both for Mathematica and WolframAlpha. Multiple sources confirm that the problem crept in circa version 11.1 of Mathematica and was fixed, since it does not to occur with Mathematica 11.3, nor 11.0.0 or 10.4.1

Comment: MMA `11.3` give a correct answer `1/360`

Comment: Also, the second limit is `139/51840`, which is correct.

Comment: I checked `WolframAlfa` and again give me `1/360`.Paste this code to Wolfram Alfa: `limit ((x + 1/2)*Ln(x) - x + Ln(2 Pi)/2 - Ln(Gamma(x+1)) + 1/(12 x)) *x^3   x approach to Infinity`

Comment: @fgrieu MMA 11.3 returns `1/360 ` and `139/51840` with `x!` in both cases.

Comment: MMA 10.4.1 returns `1/360` and `139/51840` with `Log[x!]` and `Log[Gamma[x+1]]` and `LogGamma[x+1]`.

Comment: MMA 11.0.0.0 returns `1/360`

Comment: What are we going to do with this? Do we really want to close it or is someone going to report it to WRI, we add a bug-header and keep this as a reference for future visitors?

Comment: @Halirutan (and Francois) I think it is simply a BTGF (bug that got fixed) or maybe a BTFI (I'll let you guess). Okay with me if a bug header is added. I had no issue with the question, and I voted to close mostly because there is really no good response since it appears to be working in the current version.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Yes, I agree. My only concern was that a closed question might be deleted at some point and another user with an older M version asks a very similar question. That's my only reason for keeping this post as a reference.

Comment: We decided to keep this Q&A for reference and I created a CW answer.

Comment: BTFI = Been There Found It

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Daniel Lichtblau said in the comments

> @Halirutan (and Francois) I think it is simply a BTGF (bug that got fixed) or maybe a BTFI (I'll let you guess). Okay with me if a bug header is added. I had no issue with the question, and I voted to close mostly because there is really no good response since it appears to be working in the current version.

Therefore, we will keep this Q&A open as a reference for future visitors. The issue described above seems to be a bug that is only present in **Mathematica 11.1.1** or a minor version away from it.

It is fixed in 11.2 and later versions.